# Using the globals argument of timeit.timeit

Tags: python-3.5

I am attempting to run timeit.timeit in the following class:

```
from contextlib import suppress
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess
from timeit import timeit


    class BackupVolume():
        '''
        Backup a file system on a volume using tar
        '''
        targetFile = "bd.tar.gz"
        srcPath = Path("/BulkData")
        excludes = ["--exclude=VirtualBox VMs/*",  # Exclude all the VM stuff
                    "--exclude=*.tar*"]            # Exclude this tar file

        @classmethod
        def backupData(cls, targetPath="~"):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
            '''
            Runs tar to backup the data in /BulkData so we can reorganize that
            volume. Deletes any old copy of the backup repository.

            Parameters:
            :param str targetPath: Where the backup should be created.
            '''

            # pylint: disable=invalid-name
            tarFile\
                = Path(Path(targetPath /
                       cls.targetFile).resolve())
            with suppress(FileNotFoundError):
                tarFile.unlink()
            timeit('subprocess.run(["tar", "-cf", tarFile.as_posix(),'
                   'cls.excludes[0], cls.excludes[1], cls.srcPath.as_posix()])',
                   number=1, globals=something)
```

The problem I have is that inside **timeit()** it cannot interpret **subprocess**. I believe that the **globals** argument to **timeit()** should help but I have no idea how to specify the module namespace. Can someone show me how?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think in your case `globals = globals()` in the `timeit` call would work.

**Explanation**

The `globals` argument specifies a namespace in which to execute the code. Due to your import of the `subprocess` module (outside the function, even outside the class) you can use `globals()`. In doing so you have access to a dictionary of the current module, you can find more info [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#globals).

**Super simple example**

In this example I'll expose 3 different scenarios.

1. Need to access globals
2. Need to access locals
3. Custom namespace

Code to follow the example:

```
import subprocess
from timeit import timeit
import math


class ExampleClass():
    
    def performance_glob(self):
        return timeit("subprocess.run('ls')", number = 1, globals = globals())
        
    def performance_loc(self):
        a = 69
        b = 42
        return timeit("a * b", number = 1, globals = locals())
    
    def performance_mix(self):
        a = 69
        return timeit("math.sqrt(a)", number = 1, globals = {'math': math, 'a': a})
```

1. In `performance_glob` you are timing something that needs a global import, the module `subprocess`. If you don't pass the globals namespace you'll get an error message like this `NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined`
2. On the contrary, if you pass `globals()` to the function that depends on local values `performance_loc` the needed variables for the timeit execution `a` and `b` won't be in the scope. That's why you can use `locals()`
3. The last one is a general scenario where you need both the local vars in the function and general imports. If you keep in mind that the parameter `globals` can be specified as a dictionary, you just need to provide the necessary keys, you can customize it.

Comment: When creating a custom namespace, the lookup happens ahead of time, and we are picking specific values - so there is no particular reason to go through `globals()` and `locals()`. Just use names normally. I edited the code to reflect that, along with updating the documentation link.

Comment: Also note that, when passing a custom namespace for `globals`, changes made by the code to the "globals" will impact that dictionary (even if it was initialized by looking things up in `globals()`) and *not* the global variables of the contextual code. Passing `globals=globals()` allows mutating the global variables, as long as the code under test uses the appropriate `global` statements.